# SpaceVim - Error during output processing for eslint

Tags: linux, vim

In some cases after save `.js` file in `neovim` with `SpaceVim` rc I receive errors. `:messages` output:

```
Neomake error in: function <SNR>206_AutoUpdate[56]..<SNR>206_ProcessFile[84]..<SNR>206_ParseTagline, line 51 
Neomake: Error during output processing for eslint: Vim(if):E716: Key not present in Dictionary: kind) && tagname =~# '\V' . escape(a:typeinfo.sro, '\'). 
Error detected while processing function <SNR>206_do_delayed_update[11]..<SNR>206_AutoUpdate[56]..<SNR>206_ProcessFile[84]..<SNR>206_ParseTagline: 
line   51: 
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: kind) && tagname =~# '\V' . escape(a:typeinfo.sro, '\') 
Error detected while processing function <SNR>206_do_delayed_update[11]..<SNR>206_AutoUpdate[56]..<SNR>206_ProcessFile[84]..<SNR>206_ParseTagline: 
line   51: 
E116: Invalid arguments for function has_key 
Error detected while processing function <SNR>206_do_delayed_update[11]..<SNR>206_AutoUpdate[56]..<SNR>206_ProcessFile[84]..<SNR>206_ParseTagline: 
line   51: 
E15: Invalid expression: has_key(a:typeinfo, 'kind2scope') && has_key(a:typeinfo.kind2scope, fielddict.kind) && tagname =~# '\V' . escape(a:typeinfo.sro, '\')
```

What can be the problem?

UPD. In some cases `:messages` output only has:

```
line   51:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: kind) && tagname =~# '\V' . escape(a:typeinfo.sro, '\')
Error detected while processing function <SNR>206_do_delayed_update[11]..<SNR>206_AutoUpdate[56]..<SNR>206_ProcessFile[84]..<SNR>206_ParseTagline:
line   51:
E116: Invalid arguments for function has_key
Error detected while processing function <SNR>206_do_delayed_update[11]..<SNR>206_AutoUpdate[56]..<SNR>206_ProcessFile[84]..<SNR>206_ParseTagline:
line   51:
E15: Invalid expression: has_key(a:typeinfo, 'kind2scope') && has_key(a:typeinfo.kind2scope, fielddict.kind) && tagname =~# '\V' . escape(a:typeinfo.sro, '\')
```

Comment: that is a problem of the plugin you use. Check the output of `:scriptnames` for number 206 and report the error for that specific plugin.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt thanks I try. 
In `:scriptnames` 206 line is: `206: ~/.cache/vimfiles/repos/github.com/wsdjeg/tagbar/autoload/tagbar.vim`

Comment: so it is a problem of the tagbar plugin. perhaps you can update the plugin first to see if this still happens. Else report the error on the SpaceVim or tagbar plugin home page.